# How to view Facebook 360 degree photos using a simple non-electronic VR glass?

Tags: facebook, samsung-gear-vr, immersive-mode, daydream-vr

I would like to view Facebook 360 degree photos on an Android mobile using a simple non-electronic VR glass. Is it possible?

Thank you for your time

Edit: A "simple non-electronic VR glass" means a VR glass which doesn't integrate with mobile through bluetooth. So, the mobile doesn't automatically know that I am viewing it through a VR glass.

Comment: What is in opinion a "simple non-electronic VR glass"?

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your time. It means a VR glass which doesn't integrate with mobile through bluetooth. So, the mobile doesn't automatically know that I am viewing it through a VR glass.

Comment: If the VR glass does not communicate with the phone how it is effectively just like a connected monitor or TV. How should the phone then know anything about the orientation of the VR glass to derive your head position and view angle for showing the correct part of the 360 degree image?